# Cal-Heatmap display day with hours from 9-5 only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar, visualization, heatmap

I have been using [Cal-Heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/) to create a calendar.
I am doing something like this to visualize 24 hours of a day.
I would like to only visualize the hours between 9am and 5pm on that day.
Is there any way to do this through cal-heatmap?

```
    var date = new Date(2000, 0, 5)
    var day = new CalHeatMap();
    day.init({
        itemSelector: "#day",
        domain: "day",
        subDomain: "x_hour",
        data: "dates-years.json",
        start: date,
        cellSize: 40,
        range: 1,
        legend: [2, 4, 6, 8]
    })
```